# How do I display data from nodes using Umbraco's Multinode Treepicker?

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I have gone over the [documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Backoffice-Overview/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors/Multi-Node-Tree-Picker) for this property type, and have tried a bunch of methods I pulled from the forums, but I really do not understand it at all. It seems so different from every other property type I've used so far. I need an example I can actually relate to.

Here's what I'm working with. I've got a page that displays a list of logs in a foreach loop. These logs are themselves nodes in Umbraco, with a PDF attached, a summary, a date, and a multinode treepicker that allows you to select the people that were involved in the log. I would like to display the names of the nodes chosen in the treepicker.

My code that works looks like this (with all the extraneous, already-working properties stripped out):

```
    @{
        var LogsMonthNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("LogListing");
    }
    @foreach (var node in LogsMonthNode.Children.Where("Visible"))
    {
        <h1 id="#">@node.AsDynamic().Name</h1> <!--This is the log's name.-->
        Starring: <!-- Here is where I want a foreach loop (I assume) that basically says "display the .Name of each node in the treepicker"-->
    }
```

My multinode treepicker is called "characters".

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multinode treepicker just saves the node ids of the items selected as a comma separated string. For fetching properties from it you need to first fetch the actual nodes from the node Ids as below. I am assuming your `LogsMonthNode` nodes children have multinode treepicker property with selected nodes and writing accordingly.

```
@{
    var LogsMonthNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("LogListing");
}
@foreach (var node in LogsMonthNode.Children.Where("Visible"))
{
    <h1 id="#">@node.AsDynamic().Name</h1> <!--This is the log's name.-->
    foreach (var item in Umbraco.TypedContent(node.GetPropertyValue<string>("characters").Split(',')))
    //get nodes, split ids and get content from umbraco for each id
    {
        if (item != null)
        {                    
            <h2>@item.Name</h2>
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet, that worked! And now I understand it, too! Thanks. =D